# Grab page title of a website with GTM after load

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to track 404 errors on a web app.

When you access the web app, it defaults to a "Loading Application" state until well after the DOM and Window have loaded. In this state, the page `<title>` is blank.

[image: Blank page title]

Once the application loads, the page title updates to "Error" — but this isn't picked up by Google Analytics. I have set up GTM and installed a tag that fires once the DOM has loaded and collects the page title via javascript variable, but alas it's the same issue.

Unfortunately, I have zero influence on the web app itself so need to find a solution to track these Error states via GTM.

Comment: Just because the DOM has loaded, doesn't mean that the title does not get manipulated later. Maybe your best bet here is a `MutationObserver` to watch for changes to the title element's content.

Comment: Thanks — this has sent me down the right track. I've ended up using an Element Visibility trigger to track some h1 on the page instead!